# Loop thru MySQL results loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the details of an individual customer's orders grouped by order number using PHP. I can do this rudimentary by running separate queries, but that doesn't seem efficient. Can someone help me with the most efficient way of doing this? Please see example below:

I have an "orders" MySQL table with the following structure:

```
|ordernumber|customer|quantity|sku|product |orderdate
-----------------------------------------------------
|1          |bob     |2       |aaa|producta|2012-08-30
|1          |bob     |1       |bbb|productb|2012-08-30
|1          |bob     |4       |ccc|productc|2012-08-30
|2          |jim     |10      |aaa|producta|2012-08-30
|2          |jim     |1       |ccc|productc|2012-08-30
|3          |bob     |1       |bbb|productb|2012-12-15
|3          |bob     |4       |ccc|productc|2012-12-15
```

I want to output Bob's orders in this format:

```
Customer: Bob
Order ID: 1
Order Date: 2012-08-30
Details:    *Qty*     *Sku*     *Product*
              2        aaa       producta
              1        bbb       productb
              4        ccc       productc
____________________________________________________
Customer: Bob
Order ID: 3
Order Date: 2012-12-15
Details:    *Qty*     *Sku*     *Product*
              1        bbb       productb
              4        ccc       productc
```

Comment: Run a single query and format it in php in a way you like.

Comment: Try and think of database usage as a three stage process: Query, Manipulate, Display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run a single query - select all where customer is bob and order by ordernumber.

Then I would simply iterate through the results and print the skus.

Whenever I see a new ordernumber in my iterations, I would print the formatting to start a new order (and echo all of its metadata like date, ordernumber, etc)

Here is pseudo code:

```
rows = run_sql(select * where customer = bob order by ordernumber asc)

curr_order_id = 0

foreach (row in rows)
{
  if (row[order_id] != curr_order_id)
  {
    curr_order_id = row[order_id]
    print(-----------------------)
    print(customer : row[customer])
    print(order : row[order_id])
    print(order date: row[order_date])
    print(details: *qty* *sku* *product*)
  }
  print(     row[qty] row[sku] row[product])
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I want to do, but the question is HOW to do this?

Comment: added pseudo code.. you will have to translate it into actual php + sql but it should give you the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

Your table needs something whats called **normalization**.
For example your table is redundant such that you are giving out information about **bob 5** times and out of which **2** times you are saying its **"sku"** is **ccc** and **2** times saying its **bbb**. You need to split the tables and normalize it for better performance. Read up on first **3 normal forms** believe me it will help you achieve your desired result and will open up flexibility to more complex queries.

Comment: In what way isn't this normalised? Bob is the customer for that order and there is multiple orders with bob as a customer. This is not redunant information as each instance of bob gives information about the current row.

Comment: I'm fully aware of Codd's normal forms. Even if you do add a table and  point say, sku to it then either the sku column will still have a duplicated sku (if sku is used as a primary key) or it will have duplicated ids. This is down to the data not the fact it's not normalised.

Comment: Actually, customer is normalised. Just realised there is a sku and product column, which makes it redunant. My apologies.